# Loading ArrayList of Objects from file

Tags: java, object, arraylist, load, save

I've been trying to work out saving and loading objects in Java, but I'm having some problems with the loading of the file. What I want to do here is load an ArrayList of objects called Employee, which I have serialized. I'm still getting a red wall of errors when I try to load it. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
try (FileInputStream filStrom = new FileInputStream(filpeker);
                        ObjectInputStream objektStrom = new ObjectInputStream(filStrom))
                    {
                    employeelist = (ArrayList<Employee>)objektStrom.readObject();
                    objektStrom.close();
                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Feil under lesing av fil! " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

The errors I'm getting are these:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: ovinger9.Employee; no valid constructor
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at ovinger9.EmployeeGUI$2.actionPerformed(EmployeeGUI.java:135)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Looks pretty explicit to me: `ovinger9.Employee`; ***no valid constructor***

Comment: @JimGarrison ...newInvalidClassException...

Comment: In the `Employee` class make sure you have the default constructor, also note that if you have an overridden constructor, then you have to explicitly add the default constructor.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a marshalling/unmarshalling framework - they work with plain text as well as XML

Comment: A no arg constructor is not necessarily a requirement for serialization.

Answer (score 3):

Add public constructor that takes no parameters to the `ovinger9.Employee` class (in addition to another constructor you already have there).

Comment: +1 for Keen eye and good memory...

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if your `Employee` class extends a class that is not `Serializable`, and the superclass does not have a zero argument constructor, as decribed in the [`java.io.Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) documentation. To solve it, either declare your super class as `Serializable`, or add a zero arg constructor to the super class.

Comment: I figured it out with your advice thanks! I had completely forgot about the superclass of Employee which I hadn't serialized.